# GIT mirror with FTP

Tags: git, ftp, backup, mirroring

is it possible to mirror GIT repository on an FTP server? If not, what is the best solution to backup repositories with FTP?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access (*SSH*) to the server - you can use *rsync*, [*scp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)

```
scp -r user@example.com:/home/user/repo.git /home/user/Desktop/repo.git
```

If you have *ftp* only access use [*ncftp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NcFTP)

```
ncftpget –R –v –u "user" ftp.example.com /home/user/repo.git
```

You will copy the folder with your repo to local (remote) machine.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to fully backup a git repository is to copy the directory.

If you want a real mirror, now that would be more challenging, since each repository acts as a full server. Please specify what you expect from the mirror.

Comment: I need it for backup, you should be able to recover GIT repository from it in case of server fault.

Comment: @Etam Then just copy the directory. It is as simple as that.